# How to recursively zip utf-8 files and folders from a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch, cygwin, zip

I have a folder named "Attachments2". I'm working in windows 7 and am using zip.exe downloaded from cygwin to zip this folder.

In this folder there are folders and files which have Hebrew characters in their names and content (in the files' content that is).

The files and folders' names are not preserved as the origin but the files' content is.

Please help.

Regrards,
Omer.

Comment: "The files and folders' names are preserved as the origin but the files' content is" ?? Please edit

Comment: Do you mean "...but the files' content _isn't_."? If so, what's wrong with it.

Comment: thanks, I meant that the file names and folders are not preserved as the origin but the content is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the free commandline tool `7z.exe` from [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

The [version history](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt) of 7zip explicitely mentions its UTF-8 support:

```
- Unicode (UTF-8) support for filenames in .ZIP archives. Now there are 3 modes:
    1) Default mode: 7-Zip uses UTF-8, if the local code page doesn't contain required symbols.
    2) -mcu switch:  7-Zip uses UTF-8, if there are non-ASCII symbols.
    3) -mcl switch:  7-Zip uses local code page.
```

A recursive zip command with 7zip looks like:

```
7z.exe a -mcl -tzip attachments.zip -r Attachments2\*.*
```

**Note:**
7zip's own format `.7z` does not support codepages. You have to use the `-tzip` parameter to select the `.zip` archive format.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work (files and folder names are gybrish)... any ideas ?

Comment: Which combination of switches have you tried? Please post the complete commandline.

Comment: 7z.exe a -mcu -tzip attachments333.zip -r 2013-08-07_10-16-32\*.*

Comment: it is backslash and then *.* at the end, dont know why the it is not shown

Comment: I tried the same command you posted just with different values

Comment: Are you sure that the files names are actually garbled? Or could it be that you only get a wrong display of the names? 7z.exe has an additional parameter -scsUTF-8 to list UTF-8 encoded names. You could try the switch -mcl rather than -mcu during archiving.

Comment: That's good news!